# Accessing node generated by FXML

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I've created a simple JavaFX program, using CSS and FXML for style and layout, respectively. How can I, from the main Java application, edit the nodes declared in the FXML? Specifically, how could I change the text from the `Text` object shown below:

### CSS

```
.stage {
    -fx-background-color: lightskyblue ;
    -fx-effect: innershadow(three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6), 25, 0.0, 0, 1 );
}

.time {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-font-size: 95;
    -fx-font-family: 'sans-serif';
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6), 2, 0.0, 0, 1 );
}
```

### FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="mainStage" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="stage" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <center>
    <Text fx:id="time" styleClass="time" text="Text" />
  </center>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@application.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</BorderPane>
```

### Java Program

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("layout.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
            
            stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a controller class for the FXML, with the proper annotations:

```
public class MyCtrl {
    @FXML private Text time; // name must be the same as fx:id
}
```

Declare the controller in the FXML (there are other ways too, this is probably the simplest):

```
<BorderPane fx:id="mainStage" ... fx:controller="mypackage.MyCtrl">
```

And then you can access it from within the controller, e.g. from the `initialize()` method:

```
public void initialize() {
    text.setText("xyz");
}
```

(You probably want to setup a timer in `MyCtrl.initialize()` to call `setText()` with the current time periodically.)

Comment: Currently i'm getting the following error: `javafx.fxml.LoadException: fx.controller is not a valid attribute`

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, a typo and my mistake: it is `fx:controller` (corrected above too). I am sorry!